# How can I make Facebook App page visible on mobile?

Tags: facebook, mobile, tabs

On my client's Fanpage, a third party app is running for a contest. How can I make this FB contest page available on mobile? I read the answer here:

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/10833366/461119

also

[Facebook SDK : Page Tab App returns not found in mobile Facebook App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979577/)

I do not understand it clearly.

Is the query parameter `?ref-ts` which we have to add at the end of URL?

What does it mean by "*It helps in the browser but not the app itself.*"?

Will it help to see the App on mobile and click on it to go to the contest page on FB?

Also, I found this answer:

> Works as advertised! Thank you. I was getting 404, but simply adding
>   ref=ts in my redirect URLs (I force users to use my app as a page tab)
>   fixed it! – Guillaume Boudreau

under the first link above but what is forcing users to use app as a page tab?

How can I set App as a page tab?

little bit confused.

I searched the web vigorously but did not get any clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

My observations about this issue:

- Seems like it's an ANDROID issue, Work OK on iPhone's
- Work with the link redirection services like Bit.ly (where the bit.ly link included the ref=ts)

I sent an email to Facebook for ANDROID developers.

> Hi,
>
> my iPhone's user colleagues can open links to page tab app with ref=ts
>   parameters but on Android we can't ;-(
>
> The only way we've been able to do it is when the link to the app is
>   under a bit.ly redirection link
>
> The problem is only when the links are open through the Facebook App.
>
> Thanks
>
> Let us know
>
> Max*

Answer (score 0):

You can access to your app using the next link https://apps.facebook.com/YOUR-APP-ID

In this way, you can access from a desktop or a mobile with no problem.

Comment: This only works for canvas apps. The issue still persists with page_tab apps.